# Exporting excel from apex code is retrieving headers.

Tags: apex

I have created page and controller(Without sharing) to export excel file. This code is working fine at my end. It is a part of manage package. One of our client is facing an issue while downloading the file. They only getting the header values. Data is not coming in sheet. They are able to see all data on UI. I have checked all the permission for user and he is having all permission to export file.

Comment: Without code it would be hard to tell why it's happening?

Comment: code is working fine for all clients excluding only one.

Comment: Have you checked FLS?

Comment: If it is working for everyone but a specific client think of the things that a specific client can change that would affect it. It is likely a security or FLS issue or something very specific to their data causing an error. Without knowing the implementation it is hard to say. Focus on what could be different in their org that could affect it

Comment: Is there any specific permission to export excel from apex. He is able to see all the data which is going to export.